# Windows Forms switch between Panels

Tags: winforms, panel

I'm writing a program that has two main functions. Each of the functions will have a different user interface, on a separate Panel, but only one will be visible at a time. But, how do I switch between them?

Comment: Are you using tabs to switch between the windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property of the Panel(s)

```
Panel1.Visible = True
Panel2.Visible = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the panels' `Visible` properties to show one and hide the other.