# Visual Studio Control for different tabs

Tags: c#, tabs

I'm looking for a Windows Forms tool in Visual Studio (C#) that acts like a panel, but can have a number of preset configurations of controls that can be switched between via code. The user can't change the configuration himself. Does this exist?

My thought was a TabControl, where the upper tabs are initially set to invisible upon startup, but I can switch between them in the Designer and systematically switch tab in C# code. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: You can switch between panels...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254308/windows-forms-switch-between-panels

Comment: What is the problem with the TabControl with [invisible headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316567/how-do-i-create-a-tab-control-with-no-tab-header-in-windows-form)? Users won't be able to change the control set and you can change the tab from code-behind. Well, you obviously should be able to access them in the designer - you are protecting users from unneeded data, not complicating your own design activities.

Comment: @m102 But the panels will have to be on top of each other in the designer, how am I supposed to edit the controls in the panel below easily?

Comment: You can store the `Panels` on the `TabPages` of an __invisible__ `Tab` and then `Add` them to the `Form's Controls` when you need them and `Remove` them when switching. This way you can design them (almost) perfectly and still keep their state while switching as they still are stored in the `Tab`.. Works like a charm, even without magic.